# HTML - JSON C# Asp.Net Code

Tags: c#, html, json, bar-chart, json-deserialization

I have a embeded C# code into my HTML file. Which first deserializes the JSON file:

```
[
   {
      "Subject": "TEST APP",
      "AppScores": [
         {
            "Season": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
            "year": "1"
         },
         {
            "Season": "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
            "year": "2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Subject": "TEST APP2",
      "AppScores": [
         {
            "Season": "CCCCCCCCCCC",
            "year": "3"
         },
         {
            "Season": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
            "year": "4"
         }
      ]
   } 
]
```

Can anyone help to show this on my page as it doesn't seem to work.

For the moment I am trying to get the data within the `Response.Write` to display onto the webpage. I have chosen to do this on the HTML page as I am puzzled on how to do it within MVC.

Once this is done I am then going to use the variable from Response.Write / for each to pass into a Bar Chart. Can anyone help as I am really struggling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically does not work? What do you expect to see and what are you getting?

Comment: Sorry but `doesn't seem to work` is not actually a question.

Comment: The error I am getting is that nothing is appearing on the webpage which in turn will not accept my C# code. On top of this 'Response.Write' doesn't display any value on the webpage. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code that shows what you're doing with the json.

Comment: Please see the answer below with the resolution that I am using. The current problem I am now having is contained within this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014469/c-sharp-mvc-drawing-bar-chart-from-variables-within-loop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code to display the data in line. I have replaced `Response.Write` with `Html.Raw`. This will help in displaying your text in line.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SchoolSubject";
}

<h2>SchoolSubject</h2>

@{ 
    string json = File.ReadAllText("JSON.json");
    var root = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<MyTest.Models.SchoolSubject>>(json);
    foreach (var subject in root)
    {
        @Html.Raw(subject.Subject);

        foreach (var item in subject.AppScores)
        {
            @Html.Raw(item.Season);
            @Html.Raw(item.year);
        }
    }

}
```

Lets say the class is in SchoolSubject.cs file as below

```
namespace MyTest.Models
{
    public class SchoolSubjectAppScore
    {
        public string Season { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
    }

    public class SchoolSubject
    {
        public SchoolSubject() { this.AppScores = new List<SchoolSubjectAppScore>(); }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public List<SchoolSubjectAppScore> AppScores { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Suggested Html.Raw as this is just temporary. Otherwise you may have to make sure of the validity of the data passed to it.

Comment: First error message I received was: `The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup`

Comment: Second error message I recieved was:  `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected`

Comment: Any ideas as I just copied to code straight into my HTML webpage. Thanks.

Comment: There was a closing bracket missing in the above code. I have updated it. Please try now.

Comment: Hi Martin, I still receive the Second and Third Error. I still cannot view my data within the webpage. The error happens for the missing `}` is after the second `for each` statement. The other error I am not sure about. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: So, you are getting these errors after the change I suggested in the Answer? If that is the case can you manually change `@Html.Raw` to `Response.Write` and see if you are getting errors or not?

Comment: Changed it as suggest to `Repsonse.Write` but still the same error message and I cant understand why. Error **CS1513**  `} expected` is display on the HTML webpage when the code is ran. Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated the code again. There was a silly mistake in it. It should work now. Please try now :)

Comment: Hi Martin,  This is the new error i now received on top on the other two. `Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@". `

Comment: As I am writing this on a HTML webpage is there something missing in the file? Can you identify what format you are writing it in?

Comment: I was doing it in a cshtml. I think we need to do this conversation in a chat

Comment: Same here, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to chat. How else can we do this? I can add my email on here then once you have seen it would be to edit the comment to remove my email.

Comment: Finally I figured out the issue. The problem is that you should not copy paste the `Class` definition in to your HTML. Instead you should create the class in your `Model` and refer that in the `Razor` code. Please see my updated answer

Comment: I must say this was a terrible mistake I should have figured out much earlier. I need to refresh my Razor skills :)

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your help the code is now working after you found this out, thank you. So far around the `@html.raw` I have placed `<p>` tags around this. Now I have this I am trying to put values into a bar chart. So far I have drawn the chart for this but I have the problem of reading the values in? The code I am using is: `var mychart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400) .AddTitle("School Results") .AddSeries(chartType: "column", xValue: new[] {}, yValues: new[] {}).Write(); ` Is this something you can help with? Thanks

Comment: Please `mark above as answer` for other users, if you are fine with the solution.

Comment: You have to post a new question so that it will get attention from many and your problem might get solved easier. Please make sure that when you post the question you have provided the details of the issue you are facing along with the code. Have a great day :)

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your help thus far:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014469/c-sharp-mvc-drawing-bar-chart-from-variables-within-loop/ . I have posted this question already but no response so far, any advice or help?