# C# MVC - Drawing Bar Chart from Variables within Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, loops, charts

My question is in response to:
[Showing System.Web.Helpers.Chart in a partial view from the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685302/showing-system-web-helpers-chart-in-a-partial-view-from-the-model/35013576?noredirect=1#comment57754057_35013576)

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] {  "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

Has anyone been able to use values from a loop within the xValue and yValue. Currently in the examples I have found all the values are hard coded.

I would like to use the item.season as the X and item.year as the Y from the foreach statement below(first gather subject, second gathers year and season):

```
string json2 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Assess.json");
var root = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<WebApplication1.Models.SchoolSubject>>(json2);
        foreach (var subject in root)
        {
            <h2>@Html.Raw(subject.Subject)</h2>
            foreach (var item in subject.AppScores)
            {
               <p>@Html.Raw(item.Season)</p> 
                <p>@Html.Raw(item.year)</p>
                <p>@Html.Raw(item.value)</p>
                }
            }
```

Model with Class Code contained:

```
public class SchoolSubjectAppScore
    {
        public string Season { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public class SchoolSubject
    {
        public SchoolSubject() { this.AppScores = new List<SchoolSubjectAppScore>(); }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public List<SchoolSubjectAppScore> AppScores { get; set; }
    }
```

The JSON file I have is:

```
[{"Subject": "English","AppScores": [{"Season": "Winter","year": "2009", "value" : "20" }, {"Season": "Summer","year": "2009", "value" : "38"}]}, {"Subject": "Maths","AppScores": [{"Season": "Winter","year": "2009", "value" : "10"}, {"Season": "Summer","year": "2009", "value" : "27"}]}]
```

The output on the graph I would like is two Series - Maths/English, the xValue - Season/Year and the yValue - Value.

Any ideas as I have look everywhere for help on this.

Answer (score 1):

That is easy. You just need to add your `Season` and `year` data from json to a `List` when you are in the Loop. Once you have the `List` you can convert it to an array and assign it to the Chart. See updated code below.

```
string json2 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Assess.json");
var root = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerialize().Deserialize<List<WebApplication1.Models.SchoolSubject>>(json2);

var seasons = new List<string>();
var years = new List<string>();

    foreach (var subject in root)
    {
        <h2>@Html.Raw(subject.Subject)</h2>
        foreach (var item in subject.AppScores)
        {
            <p>@Html.Raw(item.Season)</p> 
            <p>@Html.Raw(item.year)</p>

            seasons.Add(item.Season);
            years.Add(item.year);
            }
        }
```

After doing above you can add the `seasons` and `years` to the graph.

```
@{
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Chart Title")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Employee",
        xValue: seasons.ToArray(),
        yValues: years.ToArray())
    .Write();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help on this, how do I display two columns on the chart instead of one for example Maths (Blue) and English (Red). Also how do I combine the titles of Season\Year together? Is this possible, thanks for your help again Martin :)

Comment: sorry, i didn't get your question. can you update your question with details to show what you want on X and Y axis?

Comment: Hi Martin, The output on the graph I would like is two Series - Maths/English, the xValue - Season/Year and the yValue - Value.

Comment: Please show the code that you have written to achieve this goal and then I might be able to help you in fixing it if there is any issue.

Comment: Please see this link if you need to have more info on adding multiple series, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart.addseries(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Hi, I have added in a new Series and added in a Legend, the only problem is the data is the same for both and my the yaxis only display season not the year `var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400) .AddTitle("Subject Scores") .AddSeries(  name: "English",xValue: seasons.ToArray(), xField: "Seasons", yValues: values.ToArray(), yFields: "Values") .AddSeries(name: "Maths", xValue: seasons.ToArray(), yValues: values.ToArray()  ).AddLegend(name: "Engish") .Write();` Thanks for your help.